# Creating a CSS class programmatically ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, css, vb.net

I have a DIV that I would like to modify the CSS for programmatically in VB.Net/C#.

I know that, for example, I could add style attributes simply by

```
divMyDiv.Style.add("color","#ff0000")
```

but I want to add a new CSS class, together with its attributes to the DIV. So in an ideal world I would like to write something like

```
divMyDiv.Style.add(".smallRedText", "{font-size:10px; color:#ff0000}")
```

Is this even possible ? Am I missing the bigger picture ?

All help gratefully received :-)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't predefine the classes and just change the class programmaticly?

Comment: That would work - but how do I change the class programmatically ?

Comment: This seems to already be answered in the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
divMyDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "new-class")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you define the variations in css ahead of time that you know you'll need. Then, you can manipulate the `class` attribute of whatever control you need to change on the fly.

For example, you could define:

```
.smallRedText { font-size: 10px; color: #ff0000 }
.smallBlueText { font-size: 10px; color: #0000ff }
```

Then when comes time to select dynamically:

```
divMyDiv.Attributes.Add("class", whateverClassWeNeed);
```

Comment: Thanks - but what if I want to, for example, change the definition of smallRedText so that the font size was 11px ?

Comment: I am fairly certain that will require JavaScript. I know you can access stylesheets in the DOM through `document.styleSheets`, but I don't have experience using it.